# NodeJS MongoDB how to get the data outside of the function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my Code. In the mongodb Documentation it says, that I should replace the `console.dir` inside the forEach, with a callback to access the individual elements. I have tried everything in my knowledge, but got no success.

I need the data outside of the function, so I can loop through it, and get the emails of the users.

```
const client = new MongoClient(url);
  async function run() {
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db(dbMongo);
      const users = database.collection("users");

      const query = {};

      const cursor = users.find();
      if ((await cursor.count()) === 0) {
        console.log("No documents found!");
      }

      await cursor.forEach(console.dir);
    } finally {
      recipients = "";
      await client.close();
    }
  }
  run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: define "no success".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to make the run function return the results:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
const uri = "mongodb://localhost?writeConcern=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function run() {
    let docs = [] //<- Declare a variable to hold your docs
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db(dbMongo);
      const users = database.collection("users");

      const query = {};

      const cursor = users.find();
      if ((await cursor.count()) === 0) {
        console.log("No documents found!");
      }

      await cursor.forEach((doc)=>docs.push(doc.email));//<-Callback to add what you need into the docs array
      
    } finally {
      await client.close();
      return docs  //<- return the docs
    }
}

//Wrap call in iife to use await here
(async()=>{
    let results = await run().catch(console.dir);
    console.log('----- Logging Results -------')
    console.log(results)    
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a global variable array to push the data inside cursor.forEach
`cursor.forEach(doc=>{ Global_Array.push(doc); })`

Use this Array elsewhere in the code
Remember to await run() and use the global array after run is called